# Error creating user: { [Error: There are no login transports available for the requested method.] code: 'TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE' }

Tags: firebase

```
var Firebase = require("firebase");

var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://amber-fire-6500.firebaseio.com/");

myFirebaseRef.createUser({
  email    : "guosong@outlook.com",
  password : "12345678"
}, function(error) {
  if (error === null) {
    console.log("User created successfully");
  } else {
    console.log("Error creating user:", error);
  }
});
```

this is my code but I got the error as title shows.

I found this step to fix this, but finally i don't can not finish it. Because i can not find the provider settings mentioned in their document. Can anybody help?

Comment: Their document is here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html

Comment: Works fine for me here (http://jsbin.com/jokaga/edit?js,console). There probably was a temporary transport problem.

Answer (score 7):

**Update Jan 6, 2015**:

Firebase has recently released v2.1.0 of the Firebase Web / Node.js client library, which includes support for user management methods in Node.js. You should now be able to run the included snippet without encountering the `TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE` error.

---

Firebase authentication via email / password is currently web / browser only, and not supported in Node.js.