# Firebase Email/Password authentication error TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, firebase, phonegap-build

I created a basic application using PhoneGap Build that I am trying to implement a simple Email/Password authentication scheme for with Firebase. The authentication works fine in Android, but when I run it on my Windows Phone 8.1 I get the "TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE" error returned.

I looked through a lot of stuff on the interwebz, but there really isn't much out there for this kind of thing. So far I have attempted to add the InAppBrowser plugin as suggested in a few places, but that didn't resolve the issue.

The [Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-full-error) states "Redirects are not available in PhoneGap / Cordova, or local", but since it works on the same code on the Android I am wondering if that really is the issue.

My next step is going to be implementing the google authentication, but I would prefer to get this fixed instead of having to reengineer that entire portion of my application.

Help me Firebase Support... you're my only hope!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error creating user: { \[Error: There are no login transports available for the requested method.\] code: 'TRANSPORT\_UNAVAILABLE' }](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541571/error-creating-user-error-there-are-no-login-transports-available-for-the-r)

Comment: Particularly, when reading the above answers, pay attention to including cordova.js or phonegap.js and testing your inAppBrowser plugin by calling window.open