# No transports available

Tags: sockets, firebase, react-native

I recently was trying to upgrade my react-native app to use react-native 0.5.0 and firebase. According to this [article](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-05-29-react-native.html) the react-native sockets are working and the full firebase sdk should be available.

I was previously using [firebase-debug](https://github.com/badfortrains/wsExample/blob/master/firebase-debug.js) and @badfortrains [react-native fork](https://github.com/badfortrains/react-native) with success following the example project https://github.com/badfortrains/wsExample.

Since upgrading to I now am getting this error

[image: Error - No Transports Available]

When looking at the issues on the react-native repo I came across this https://github.com/sjmueller/firebase-react-native/issues/1

@stephenplusplus says he pushed a bunch of buttons and activated magic. Any idea what he is referencing??

There is also this other SO question [Error creating user: { [Error: There are no login transports available for the requested method.] code: 'TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE' }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541571/error-creating-user-error-there-are-no-login-transports-available-for-the-r)

Any help on understanding the issue between using badfortrains with firebase-debug and the newest version of react-native with firebase would be appreciated.

I don't know if I am implementing something incorrectly or if the article mentioned above is a bit overzealous.

Thoughts???

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to show the relevant, non-obfuscated code to get any help here. Also, see [react on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/react). There are a lot of discussions demonstrating that auth doesn't work yet with native.

Comment: I am assuming there is a problem somewhere in the xcode project settings though I don't know where. I was able to create a new project using the react-native-cli generator and then copy and paste over all of my components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough starting a new project from scratch using the react-native-cli generator I was able to copy and paste all of my components over to the new project and have everything work perfectly.

I am not sure where the problem is but I will assume for now that there is an issue with the xcode project settings when trying to upgrade. Despite cleaning the project, resetting xcode to default settings, removing all derived data, restarting the package bundler, nothing worked until I created a new project.

This should prove there is nothing wrong with the JavaScript frameworks but rather it is some obscure xcode project setting. I will continue to look for a solution other than spinning a new project but for now it works.